# SwiftUI Edit Struct from List

Tags: list, struct, swiftui, identifiable

I am attempting to have a list that when a cell it tapped it changes the `hasBeenSeen` `Bool` value within the `State` object itself.

```
struct State: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    var hasBeenSeen: Bool = false
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let states: [State] = [
        State(name: "Oregon", hasBeenSeen: true),
        State(name: "California", hasBeenSeen: true),
        State(name: "Massachussets", hasBeenSeen: false),
        State(name: "Washington", hasBeenSeen: true),
        State(name: "Georgia", hasBeenSeen: false)
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(states, id: \.id) { state in
                    StateCell(state: state)
                }
            }.navigationBarTitle(Text("States"))
        }
    }
}

struct StateCell: View {
    var state: State
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(state.name)
            Spacer()
            if state.hasBeenSeen {
                Image(systemName: "eye.fill")
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
//            state.hasBeenSeen.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

My original thought is that I need to make `hasBeenSeen` to a `@State` var but that doesn't seem to work. How can I make this `Bool` val editable from a list?

Answer (score 0):

Views in SwiftUI are immutable - they are just structures - so you can't change their properties. That's why SwiftUI has a concept of a `@State` property wrapper. When you change "state" property, SwiftUI actually updates the state value, not the view's property value (which is, again, immutable).

So, you need to set `@State` on the `states` property within your view. (You'd also need to change the name, since identifier `State` is already taken by the `State` property wrapper - so I just changed it to `StateEntity`)

```
@State var states: [StateEntity] = [
      StateEntity(name: "Oregon", hasBeenSeen: true),
      // ... etc
   ]
```

That's not enough, though, since when you pass an element of the `states` array (a `StateEntity` value) to a child view, you're just passing a copy.

For that, you'd need a binding. A binding allows child views to modify state properties of parent views, without owning the data. So, the child view's property should use the `@Binding` property wrapper:

```
struct StateCell: View {
    @Binding var state: StateEntity

    // ...
}
```

SwiftUI made it easy to get the binding of state property by using the projected value, which in this case is `$states`.

However, you need to pass a binding not to the entire array, but to a specific element of that array. That, unfortunately (and rather annoyingly), is a bit trickier. You need to get the index of the element, and given the index, access the binding like so: `$state[index]`.

One way is to do a `ForEach` over indices of `states`:

```
var body: some View {
   NavigationView {
      List {
         ForEach(states.indices) { index in
            StateCell(state: self.$states[index])
         }
      }.navigationBarTitle(Text("States"))
   }
}
```